# Trying to add those who opened a mailing to a group - result, all contacts added

Tags: civimail, groups

We are trying to add contacts who opened a CiviMail mailing so that we can exclude them from receiving the next mailing.  I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle that but here is what we did:

1. From CiviMail reports, we opened the "Advanced Search" next to Tracked Opens and the result shows 6176 contacts who opened the message.
2. We chose "All 6176 records" from the Select Contacts options, then Add Contacts to Group from the Actions menu.
3. On the next screen where you can select the specific group to add to or create a new group, the number of selected contacts jumps to 78,247 which is the total number of contacts in our database.

Tried the above steps with an existing group, with creating a new group and with tags and got the same result.

Tried to test the above steps in the sandbox but since there are no previous mailings, I could not complete the steps to replicate and test.  We have some pretty advanced permissioning set up so it might just be a problem on our system.  Can someone try to replicate to see if you encounter the same result?